# Div's don't move when window resizes

Tags: html, css

I've got 2 divs on top of another div, but when I resize the window they stay put, instead of moving with the div behind them. I thought that if there position is relative they move along with the previous div, but it doesn't seem to work like this. What am I missing?

CSS and HTML below, simplified.

```
<div class="wrapper" style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;">
<div id="0">
            <img src="0.gif" width="960px" alt="" />
            <div class="top">
                <div id="tag" ><img src="tag.png" alt="" /></div>
                <div id="tag2"><img src="5500.png" alt="" /></div>
            </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And CSS like this:

```
#0 {
        clear:                  right;
        z-index:                0;
}    
.top {
        float:                  left;
        z-index:                1;
        clear:                  left;
        position:               relative;

}

#tag {
        margin-top:             -500px;
        margin-left:            -600px;


}

#tag2{
        margin-left:            750px;

}
```

Comment: @Jordy not entirely sure, played around a lot with it, must have forgotten removing it. Removing now.

Comment: My eyes hurt. Side note, it's not recommended to have id's begin with a number.

Comment: What browser are you seeing this behavior in, and could you show us the DOCTYPE for the page?

Comment: @MatthewBishop Firefox and Safari. Doctype is <!DOCTYPE html>.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder you're probably right, but I'd be helped more with some constructive feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're expecting the `top` div, with its associated `tag` divs, to move with the `0.gif` image when you resize the page.  Instead, it's moving relative to the left edge of the `wrapper` div, which is pegged to the left-hand side of the screen.  You will probably get the result you want by adding `width: 960px` to the style of your `.wrapper` div.

For further enlightenment, check the bounding boxes on each of your divs.  You may find that a temporary `border: 2px solid green` style helps clear things up.